# Hibernate method to check existence or row in table but not return row

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need to implement a DAO method to check existence of a row in a table and return a boolean value accordingly. A crude version is shown:

```
public boolean check(Integer bookId) {
    logger.info(BookDAOImpl.class.getName() + ".check() method called.");

    return bookId.equals(this.get(bookId).getBookId());
}
```

I don't need to return the row found.

As this is only for a demo application, I'm using:

```
@Override
public boolean check(Integer bookId) {
    logger.info(PersonDAOImpl.class.getName() + ".check() method called.");

    try {
        Book book = this.get(bookId);
        return bookId.intValue() == book.getBookId().intValue();
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know why you want to implement such method, what the basic idea behind this?

Comment: As per the question, to literally test the existence of a row in a table and return a boolean field accordingly.

Comment: ..and how u will be sure that after returning from `get(bookId);` no other transaction commits the session and `bookId` get changed.?

Comment: A valid question but as this is only a simple demo application, I'm not really concerned with concurrency issues. bookId is the key anyway so that should never change.

Comment: Okay but this is not good practice, One more thing I will like to add. Use `Criteria` API along with `Projection` and select only one column instead of selecting all columns.

Comment: If by this you mean I could restrict the `get` to just `personId`, then that's helpful. I've not use `Criteria` before because I'm a bit of a Hibernate newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to optimize the check in the interest of performance.

Let me clarify like this:
There are three steps in getting a row:
 1. Making a method call/request over the network
 2. Oracle scanning and finding the row(s) that match (with or without
    index)
 3. Copying the row data and bringing them back

The costs associated with (1) and (2) are huge, whereas the cost of (3) is small.
So, IMHO there is no point in trying to optimize the amount of data returned.

For example, if it takes 120ms just for checking, it may take only 125ms for getting the data.
There will hardly be 5% difference in normal cases.

Note:
 - If your WHERE condition uses indexes, (2) will also become less
   costly
 - If you are selecting 50 to hundreds of columns, then it makes sense to find a way to do this.

Suggestion:
Unless you are selecting 50+ columns, don't bother. Just get the full data and check resultList.size().

Comment: Good advice. This is only for a demo app. I've posted my final method.

Comment: Glad to help. One more thing: you may want to catch NullPointerException instead of index out of bounds. Also you can totally omit the try catch and just do this if you like:  return book==null?false:bookId.intValue() == book.getBookId().intValue();

Comment: `Where` on primary key (considering bookid is primary key) will not be costly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply query the database using hibernate with bookId. If any resultset is returned return true or else false.